# How to stop download prompt in chrome using protractor

Tags: angular, jasmine, protractor

Chrome options:

```
'chromeOptions': {
    args: [
        'disable-extensions',
        'safebrowsing-disable-extension-blacklist',
        'safebrowsing-disable-download-protection',
        // 'show-fps-counter=true'
        '--disable-save-password-bubble',
        '--safe-mode'
    ],

    prefs: {
        'excludeSwitches': ['enable-automation'],
        'useAutomationExtension': false,
        'safebrowsing': {
            'enabled': true,
        },
        download: {
            'directory_upgrade': true,
            // 'default_directory':downloadsPath
            'prompt_for_download': false,
            'default_content_settings.popups': 0
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. I cannot find what you want exactly. Please, explain it more.

Comment: Add it in your question field, too.

Answer (score 1):

What version of protractor are you using?
The below should work:

```
chromeOptions: {
    prefs: {
        'download': {
            prompt_for_download: false,
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have used  protractor version 5.4.2

Comment: I am using same as you suggested but it's not working

Answer (score -1):

Change `chromeOptions` to `goog:chromeOptions`